# Organizing SCSS files in NextJS

Tags: sass, next.js

I'm getting an error when I try to organize my SCSS files in seperate folders and import them into my style.scss file. I can't seem to find any documention on how to fix this. Any suggestions?

[image: error]

[image: package.json]

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a `next.config.js` file in the root with the following content:

```js
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
module.exports = withSass()
```